# Couldn't communicate with a helper application

Tags: macos, dyld, macos-big-sur

I upgraded my OSX to macOS Big Sur version 11.1. Ever since I got this problem when trying to sign in in Xcode:

[image]

at the time I had an earlier version of xcode (12.2). I upgraded to Xcode 12.3 and the problem disappeared but then I came back up again. What can I do to fix this?

## What I tried

- rebooting in safe mode, didn't help
- upgrading Xcode, solved the problem temporarily
- tried to rebuild the dynamic link editor cache as suggested [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251084960?answerId=251084960021#251084960021) but it was a dead end:

```
sudo update_dyld_shared_cache –force 
This tool is deprecated.
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem, nothing helps